# spring static resource with controller requestmapping

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC project: here are my files

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**dispatcher-servlet**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

**MainController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public ModelAndView home()
    {
        String view="home";
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView(view);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head></html>
```

My webaps hosts with URL
   `localhost:8080/projectName/test/home`
but it doesn't load my static resource i.e. bootstrap.css. it should work because I have put my static resource at proper location `webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.css`

Q: why my static resource is being routes from controller path.. why its showing 404 not found.??
    `localhost:8080/projectName/test/resources/css/bootstrap.css`

why controller path "test" is appending with URL when spring wants to look-up static resource.

Comment: try to visit: localhost:8080/projectName/resources/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: You are using a relative path for the css resource. Try using an absolute path as mentioned in the comment by @Bob.Z

Comment: my static resource is on right place. I mean when I try to visit,
 localhost:8080/projectName/resources/css/bootstrap.css it returns my CSS.

But my question is when my application loads my controller is not able to honor static resource.... it searches in :
localhost:8080/projectName/test/resources/css/bootstrap.css,,, and then obviously it will 404, because resources are not under this location.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid url problems use JSTL's `<c:url` tag OR `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

for example in your case:

```
<link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>'
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

OR

```
<link href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css'
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

<sub>Note: for first example import JSTL tag library in top of jsp before use.
like:</sub>

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it run.. My home.jsp should have to include my static resources like this:

"../" prefix of resources makes controller route to honor static resources.

Comment: No, that's pretty stupid ! You've allready been told to use absolute paths ! Simple use "/" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Cuz the configuration of "/resources/" point to the "resources" directory of `WebRoot`, so the problem becomes clear, just use

```
<link href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to reference the static resources. 

Besides, there is also another way to solve this problem, that is to configure the **base** tag like following,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="<%=basePath %>">
    <title></title>
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
....
```

both will work fine, hope you can help:)